# c# posting to API via button click

Tags: c#, api, post

I've created a form that will Generate JSON code when filled in, i need it to post to an API on a button press, using `RestSharp`.

[image]

I've tried adding the `richTextBox1.Text` into the JsonBody and in the `RestRequest` but still it doesn't get a response.

Comment: Welsome to StackOverflow. Please take a tour and see How to Ask. Specifically post all your code, error messages etc. as copy-pasted text, **not** images/links.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/Request/RestRequest.cs) I see the RestRequest constructor you are using expects a URL as the first parameter but you are giving it the text of your text box. Surely the text is not both the URL and the body contents.